# If the real part of an entire function is bounded from above by $K|z|^\alpha$, then it is $O(|z|^\alpha)$

Tags: complex-analysis

If for some positive $ K, \alpha, r_o, f $ entire, 
$$\operatorname{Re} (f(z)) \leq K |z|^\alpha \qquad \forall |z| \geq r_o$$
how can I prove then that:
$$| \operatorname{Re}(f(z))| \leq K'|z|^\alpha \qquad \forall |z| \geq r_o$$
for some positive $K'$

Comment: $f$ being what?

Comment: False: Consider the real part of $z^2.$

Comment: sorry @zhw. and G.Sassatelli fixed the mistakes

Comment: Ty @Homegrown Tomato. I am new to this